# How to prevent java.lang.IllegalAccessError with JDK11?

Tags: java, testing, classloader, java-11

We receive the follow exception in our test system. Any idea how we can prevent this exception for example with a command line switch. And any idea how this exception can occur?

Can the completely access check be disabled in a test system that use intensively reflection and class loading?

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class java.io.File (in module java.base) cannot access class javax.print.PrintException (in module java.desktop) because module java.base does not read module java.desktop
    at java.io.File.exists(File.java)
    at jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:1199)
    at jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:314)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:697)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
```

Comment: Share code which results in exception. I witnessed similar errors while using Jmockit  and with version upgrade it vanished

Comment: The exception suggests that something that instrumented java.io.File with a reference to javax.print.PrintException. What tool is doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solve the problem by updating JMockit version 1.31 with the current version 1.44. It look like the old version is not compatible with the current version.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run it by adding the following command argument.

```
--add-reads java.base=java.desktop
```

Comment: This should not be needed.  The java.desktop module already exports the javax.print package, to every module.

Comment: @VGR but that does not mean that the `java.base` module *reads* `java.desktop`

Comment: java.base does not read any module so VGR's workaround may help until the real issue is diagnosed. They has to something instrumenting the code in java.base with a reference to javax.print. Is there mocking in the picture by any chance?